# Filtering in tastypie - verify GET request

Tags: django, tastypie

I am facing a small issue:

```
class EntryResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Entry.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'entry'
        authorization = Authorization()
        filtering = {
            "slug" : {'exact','startswith',},
            "title" : ALL,
        }
```

Above is my resource class. While the filtering works fine, I need to customize it as follows:

if "slug" field (using slug__startswith) in my request has length less than 2, reject the filter request or add extra characters. I am unable to do so. The reason is I have 1 million rows and I dont want such queries to scan the rows unnecesarily

Comment: in short you can say i need validation for FILTERING in GET query in Tastypie..

Answer (score -1):

Override the ModelResource.build_filters() function to add the validation you need.

Comment: build_filter will make things complex (i feel so..) can u just share a small snaps for above example, how to check for constraints in our filter??

Comment: you're really lazy (i feel so..).  You can just check the filters, modify them if necessary, and then call the base class build_filters().  Should be maybe 5-10 lines of code?